# can't create product using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to create a product, here is my code.

```java
//request to create/save a product
@RequestMapping(value = "/create_product",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveProduct(@ModelAttribute("product") Products product) // Products is the name of the Entity class and creating a productObjcet from it 
{
    productService.saveProduct(product);
    return "showInventory";
}
```

```xml
<form th:action="@{/create_product}" th:object = "${product}" method="POST"><!-- product object is passed here as named on the createformMethod Attribute Name -->
  <!-- Creating a product  -->
  <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Product Category:</label>
      <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" name="product_category" th:field="*{product_category}" class="span11" placeholder="Product name"/>
      </div>
  </div>
```

And that's the error that I am facing when I am trying to connect to the request.

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
> /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Tue Sep 28 04:05:58 EDT 2021 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
> Found, status=404). No message available

Comment: Do you have a "showInventory" page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@RequestBody` annotation in passing parameters of your function that it recognizes a **JSON** object with the model of the `Products` class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create_product",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveProduct(@RequestBody Products product){
    productService.saveProduct(product);
    return "showInventory";
}
```